# Is it possible to do complex SQL queries using Django?

Tags: sql, django

I have the following Script to get a list of calculated index for each day after specific date:

```
with test_reqs as (
 select id_test, date_request, sum(n_requests) as n_req from cdr_test_stats
 where
 id_test in (2,4) and -- List of Ids included in index calc
 date_request >= 20170823 -- Start date (end date -> Last in DB -> Today)
 group by id_test, date_request
),
date_reqs as (
 select date_request, sum(n_req) as n_req
 from test_reqs
 group by date_request
),
test_reqs_ratio as (
 select H.id_test, H.date_request, 
 case when D.n_req = 0 then null else H.n_req/D.n_req end as ratio_req
 from test_reqs H
 inner join date_reqs D
 on H.date_request = D.date_request
),
test_reqs_index as (
 select HR.*, least(nullif(HA.n_dates_hbalert, 0), 10) as index_hb
 from test_reqs_ratio HR
 left join cdr_test_alerts_stats HA
 on HR.id_test = HA.id_test and HR.date_request = HA.date_request
)
select date_request, 10-sum(ratio_req*index_hb) as index_hb
from test_reqs_index
group by date_request
```

Result:

```
---------------------------
| date_request | index_hb |
---------------------------
|   20170904   |  7.5508  |
|   20170905   |  7.6870  |
|   20170825   |  7.4335  |
|   20170901   |  7.7116  |
|   20170824   |  1.6568  |
|   20170823   |  0.0000  |
|   20170903   |  5.1850  |
|   20170830   |  0.0000  |
|   20170828   |  0.0000  |
---------------------------
```

The problem is that I want to get the same in Django and **avoid to execute the raw query using the cursor.**

Many thanks for any suggestion.

Comment: It would be easier to answer if you show your models and explain what you want to query.

Answer (score 0):

Without going deep into the specifics of your query, I'd say the Django ORM has enough expressiveness to handle most problems, but generally, would require you to redesign the query from the ground up. You would have to use subqueries and joins instead of the CTE's, and you might end up with a solution that does some of the work in Python land instead of the DB.

Taking this into account the answer is: depends. Your functional requirements, such as performance and data size play a role.

Another solution worth considering is declaring your SQL query as a view, and at least in the case of Postgres, use something like [django-pgviews](https://github.com/mypebble/django-pgviews) to query it with Django ORM almost as if it were a model.